# How do I use the data from a full sample to inform my estimates about a subgroup?

Tags: standard-deviation, subset

Consider a sample of size $N$ with various observed characteristics: for example, gender and blood pressure. For the overall sample we have the average $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ of blood pressure.

In this case we're interested in the blood pressure for males only. We can obviously compute $\mu_M$ and $\sigma_M$. But doesn't this overstate our uncertainty? In other words, aren't we leaving out information contained in the rest of the sample?

Is there a good approach for combining the overall sample data with the data from our subgroup of interest to attain a more "accurate" measure of our uncertainty?

Comment: I would like to suggest the answer will depend on additional assumptions you make. If there were such a procedure, then what would prevent you from taking your subgroup, throwing in billions of data from other datasets, and applying the procedure to the collective dataset to get "more information" about the subgroup?  This is the basis of the paradox of "shrinkage" and the James-Stein estimator.  See http://healthcare-economist.com/2010/10/05/shrinkage-and-the-james-stein-estimator/ for a quick, elementary overview.

Comment: This was a very helpful comment, thanks! I am still wrapping my head around these ideas and how to apply them in my situation. For those who come later, here is another good resource: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/other/Article1977.pdf

Comment: There are a variety of situations where one can regard the other data as providing some information; this is used in the notion of [credibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credibility_theory#Actuarial_credibility), for example, where essentially Bayesian ideas are used to give weight to both the information in a small highly-relevant sample and a larger but less-relevant one.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b! For those who want to construct a confidence interval around a James-Stein interval: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~omkar/329/chapter1.pdf